# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_secure_storage:classpath'

Tags: flutter, security, storage

I got an error like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_secure_storage'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_secure_storage:classpath'.
   > Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.1/builder-3.3.1.jar'.
         > Connection reset
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':flutter_secure_storage' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I update my flutter to 1.22.2  I never get past the "assembleDebug" stage and get this message in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) package as in their official document.

> Configure Android version
>
> In [project]/android/app/build.gradle set minSdkVersion to >= 18.

```
android {
    ...
    
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 18
        ...
    }

}
```